# Database Table Synchronization Without Table Dropping?

Tags: database

My company's workflow relies on two MSSQL databases: one for web content data and the other is the ERP.  I've been doing some proof of concept on some tools that would serve as an intermediary that builds a relationship between the datasets, and thus far its proving to be monumentally faster.

Instead of reading out to both datasets, I'd much rather house a database on the local Linux box that represents the data I'm working with.  That way, its less pressure on the system as a whole.

What I don't understand is if there is a way to update this new database without completely dropping the table each time or running through a punishing line by line check.  If the records had timestamps, this would be easy...but they don't.

Does anyone have any tips?  Am I missing some crucial feature I don't know about, or am I 
SOL?

Finally, is there one preferred database stack out there anyone thinks might work better than another?  I'm not committed to any technology at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about the `MERGE` statement in SQL? It allows update or inserts on existing tables.

I assume your tables have primary keys even though you say there is no timestamp.

Comment: Gonna check into why we aren't using it tomorrow.  Thanks!